# Spring CSRF multiparfilter breaks

Tags: spring, csrf, multipartform-data

I have a multipart form with a file upload which gets posted as seen below in Chrome developer tools -

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryUkhJ5180JIBYXzLm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_csrf"

8d7f28ad-f436-473c-964e-fe41c42c80e4
------WebKitFormBoundaryUkhJ5180JIBYXzLm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_csrf"

8d7f28ad-f436-473c-964e-fe41c42c80e4
------WebKitFormBoundaryUkhJ5180JIBYXzLm--
```

The data seems to have a proper multipart boundary and the _csrf token included. My Spring application is configured as below for CSRF and multipartfilter -

Beans -

```
<bean id="tokenRepo"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository">
</bean>

<bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <property name="errorPage"
        value="/WEB-INF/files/AccessDenied.html" />
</bean>

<bean id="csrfFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="tokenRepo" />
    <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map>
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="
          csrfFilter" />
    </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartFilter" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter">
</bean>
```

web.xml -

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>   
<filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

security.xml -

```
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <http />
</b:beans>
```

I am using Spring Framework version 4.1.6.RELEASE and Spring Security version 4.0.2.RELEASE and Tomcat 7.

With this setup, the request does not pass multipartfilter and/or CSRF filter - I do not see it entering the filter placed after these 2 in web.xml.

If I change my server's context.xml opening context tag to include allowCasualMultipartParsing="true", the request passes into the next filter after multipartfilter and CSRF filter but when it reaches my controller, Apache Commons FileUpload finds it empty. I have tried wrapping the request in HttpServletRequestWrapper in order to typecast it in different ways but I could not salvage the request.

Comment: Owing to the brokenness of multipartfilter, my temporary fix is to exclude my multipart URL from the CSRFFilter, let it pass to the controller and then check the token against the session. Frustrating but works!